# Нужны ли запятые, где два обстоятельства подряд

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обстоятельство

Прошу сказать, нужны ли запятые в следующих предложениях.

«Андрей Иванов живет в Москве(,) в общежитии»
«После института он хочет работать на заводе(,) в лаборатории».

Answer (score 5):

В таких предложениях всё зависит от акцентов.
Возможны оба варианта – с запятой и без нее – в зависимости от смысла, который в конечном итоге задает интонацию и расставляет знаки препинания.

*Андрей Иванов живет в Москв**Е**, в общеж**И**тии.* Здесь важен тот факт, что Андрей живет в Москве. После запятой идет уточнение-присоединение.

*Андрей Иванов живет в Москве в общеж**И**тии.* В таком случае не так важен факт проживания в Москве, логическое ударение смещается на последнее слово.

*После института он хочет работать на зав**О**де, в лаборат**О**рии.* Подчеркивается факт желания работать именно на заводе, а конкретно, в лаборатории.

*После института он хочет работать на заводе в лаборат**О**рии.* Здесь понятно, что работа на заводе уже не новая информация – подчеркивается только то, что человек хочет работать именно в лаборатории.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121287/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 2):

**Первый комментарий (не ответ)**

**Теория** к заданному вопросу, а также  к дискуссии по нему

Новые «откровения» нашего участника, как это ни странно, изменили мое видение ситуации: у нас, оказывается, **не две, а три идеологии.**

1. **Мы должны писать строго по правилам**, так как правовое поле – это вещь необходимая, а в таком случае  **интонационный анализ является лишним**.
2. **Мы должны писать по правилам, но по этим правилам писать невозможно.**
   А интонационный анализ — это вообще **бред**!

**Цитата** (вот уж спасибо за нее, очень к месту пришлась!): «Розенталь — это очень плохая формализация. Максимум, на 2 из 10. Пункты плохо сформулированы, ничего не сгруппировано, не скомпанованно, пункты включают друг друга, пункты противоречат друг другу и тд. Темы в справочнике Розенталя — это большая дымящаяся куча хаотично сброшенных пунктов, просто нет ничего лучше».  (Орфография источника сохранена.)

А где же выход? Без правил, без интонации — а как ? Трудно сказать, но у нас есть уникальная возможность **увидеть это на практике.**

3. **Мы должны писать по правилам.**

Наша система  письма прошла долгий путь развития, но только в 1956 году была создана редакция первого свода, причем **в тезисном варианте**.  Поэтому Правила Розенталя – это настоящий подвиг человека, всю жизнь посвятившего подробному  **раскрытию и изложению** этих тезисов.

При оценке правил надо также учитывать уровень развития общества того времени и его информационные возможности. Вот и хотелось бы, чтобы  пользователи языка  относились  с большим уважением   как к правилам, так и к написавшим их людям.

Теперь многое изменилось, и  создание более **совершенной редакции** – это дело времени, а пока мы ориентируемся именно на этот сборник. Что касается **интонационного анализа, то он не конкурирует с правилами, а дополняет их.**

Пояснение

Наша речь основана на тесном взаимодействии **грамматических и фонетических** законов, хотя мы иногда  стараемся этого не замечать и даже отрицаем. **Структура предложений** (прежде всего, порядок слов) зависит от расстановки тонических (логических) ударений и пауз. Даже само название  –  знак препинания как  задержка в речи –  говорит нам об этом!  **Обязательное «тонирование» предложения**  – это та **реальность,** которую невозможно отрицать и нельзя не учитывать.  Другими словами, «читай не так, как пономарь, а с чувством, с толком, с расстановкой».

Comment: Я не говорил, что интонация не важна, я говорил, что одно и тоже предложение может быть произнесено с сотней различных тонких отличий, которые не будут фиксироваться в пунктуации, так как это невозможно и бессмысленно, и это не будет работать как пунктуация, так как в таком случае будет невозможна общая согласованность. Что это детское переиначивание моих слов?

Comment: Jim Korbett, давайте с вами договоримся. Считайте, что ваши "каникулы" закончились и вы будете строго соблюдать правила форума. Оценочная лексика негативного содержания с переходом на личности на форуме запрещена . Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от нее. Тогда я буду отвечать на ваши комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

**Второй комментарий (не ответ)**

**Образец  применения интонационного анализа** на конкретном примере

Вопрос: Прошу сказать, нужны ли запятые в следующих предложениях.

(1) «Андрей Иванов живет в Москве (,) в общежитии». (2) «После института он хочет работать на заводе (,) в лаборатории».

**Вместо вступления**

Это пример обычного вопроса, на которые мы отвечаем ежедневно,  но так уж получилось, что он попал в центр внимания. Это отчасти связано с темой, которая не раз уже здесь обсуждалась, а именно **различение неоднородных и уточняющих обстоятельств.**

Данный  вопрос в правилах Розенталя изложен действительно формально, что отчасти можно понять. Предложенное решение имеет очень частный характер и  не соответствует практическому применению в большинстве случаев. Это как раз тот момент, когда желательно использовать **дополнительный интонационный  анализ**. Но можно ли было говорить об этом в то время, когда составлялись правила!

1. **Правило Розенталя** :  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

§ 22. Уточняющие члены предложения

Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому). Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства и определения.

**1. Уточняющие обстоятельства места**

В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться или не рассматриваться как уточняющее обстоятельство. Ср.:

Впереди на дороге толпились люди (т. е. в передней части дороги). — Впереди, на дороге, толпились люди (т. е. сама дорога находилась впереди);

Далеко в лесу раздавались удары топора (слушатель находится в лесу). — Далеко, в лесу, раздавались удары топора (слушатель находится вне леса);

Дети расположились на поляне между кустами (поляна окружена кустами, а на самой поляне их нет). — Дети расположились на поляне, между кустами (кусты находятся на самой поляне).

Это то самое правило, которое сложно применить и  которое вызывает большое количество вопросов. На практике писатель обычно **изображает пространство с помощью  художественных средств,** а обособление использует для обозначения характера отношений между обстоятельствами.

**Примечание.** Общая семантика всех обособленных оборотов такова: это или уточнение, или, напротив, актуализация и придание значимости. В нашем случае при обособлении мы будем обозначать **уточняющий** характер отношений.

2. Поэтому вместо правила мы используем грамматику (собственно говоря, все правила в русском языке имеют грамматический характер). Существует **три вида отношений** между обстоятельствами: однородные, неоднородные, уточняющие. Мы будем выбирать между  **двумя значениями**: неоднородным (нет запятой) и уточняющим (ставится запятая).  Таким образом,  мы сравниваем **две структуры:** простое  предложение  и предложение с обособлением.
3. **Простое предложение**
   Согласно интонационной модели, простое предложение  в общем случае состоит из двух фонетических фраз: повышении тона – произносительная пауза – понижении тона.  Знаков препинания в простом предложении нет, но мы при  прочтении «угадываем»  его двухчастную структуру.

(1) Андрей Иванов живет в МосквЕ // в общежИтии.

(2) «После института /он хочет работать на завОде // в лаборатОрии».

В этих предложениях мы расставили тонические ударения  и обозначили произносительные паузы. Дополнительно произносительной паузой выделено необособленное обстоятельство в начале предложения (2).

**Что характерно для такой схемы.** Хотя в каждом предложении по два тонических ударения, но ударение в конце всего предложения выделено **в большей степени** (так выражается идея его законченности),  первое же ударение мы практически оставляем вообще без внимания. Соответственно, получается как бы логическое выделение второго обстоятельства. В то же время обстоятельства при неоднородных отношениях мыслятся **как равные**  – это две **разные координаты** (в каком городе, в каком доме).

**4. Простое предложение с обособлением**

При обособлении структура предложения меняется, но в каком плане?  Деление на фразы остается прежним, только **подчеркивается пауза** и первое тоническое ударение получает дополнительное **силовое выделение**.

(1) Андрей Иванов живет в Москв**Е**,  // в общежИтии.

(2) «После института /он хочет работать на зав**О**де,  // в лаборатОрии».

Теперь, при равном интонационном выделении, мы воспринимаем отношения между обстоятельствами как **уточняющие** (второе обстоятельство уточняет первое), причем это уточнение подчеркнуто. Первое обстоятельство становится  семантически  более значимым (нам прежде всего важно, в каком городе, это основная координата), вторая же дается как дополнение.

**5. Вывод**

**Пространственная структура**  в приведенных предложениях  изначально ясна и не требует специального обозначения. В то же время с помощью обособления можно  (1) представить  информацию как **основную и уточняющую** или  (2) **не делать этого.**  Поэтому характер отношений (неоднородные или уточняющие)  выбирает сам автор, не прибегая к предложенной в правилах **жесткой схеме** (кусты на поляне или поляна между кустами).

Answer (score -1):

Да, нужна. В официальной терминологии это называет «уточнение», но я называю это «ограничение-уточнение» Взгляните на несколько примеров:
Дети расположились на поляне, между кустами.(Сначала говорится о поляне, а затем вся поляна ограничивается до места между кустами, тем самым уточняется местоположение.)
Впереди, на том берегу, находится дерево.(Сначала говорится о всем пространстве впереди, а затем это пространство ограничивается, тем самым уточняется местоположение.)
«Андрей Иванов живет в Москве, в общежитии.(Тут тоже самое.)

Запятая не ставиться между двумя обстоятельствами места только тогда, когда они не являются серией уточнений, а относятся друг к другу. Вот несколько примеров:

Спереди, на столе, ... = Все пространство спереди ограничивается местом на столе.
Спереди на столе ... = На передней части стола.

Comment: Вы несправедливо ставите минус за ответ Александра, он-то его вам не поставил. Я, к примеру, тоже не ставлю минусы, причем никогда,  вам его поставил кто-то еще.  Я предполагаю, что отрицательную оценку вы получили даже не  за сам ответ, а за использование на форуме оценочной лексики по отношению к участникам. Она здесь не приветствуется, а  в экспрессивном и негативном варианте  вообще запрещена.  Это указано в правилах,  и вас могут наказать за это модераторы форума.

Comment: Я поставил минус потому, что считаю его ответ не просто неправильным, а вводящим в заблуждение, что намного хуже. Человек из Китая, надрывал жопу несколько лет, изучая иностранный язык. Он приходит на форум, а его кормят какими-то семантико-фонетическими теориями, которые нигде полноценно не формализованы и которые разделяет 2 с половиной филолога.

Comment: Jim Korbett, ваш комментарий – это просто «шедевр», жаль, что его, вероятно, удалят, да и за вас я опасаюсь. Но веселите вы меня очень неплохо, у вас просто к этому талант. Спасибо за хорошее настроение.  К сожалению, в ваших «откровениях» я не вижу какой-либо конкретной мысли, с которой можно   начать рассуждение и приводить для вас какие-либо доказательства и примеры.

Comment: У меня тоже есть определенные проблемы,  формализм наших правил зашкаливает. Они способны искажать художественную мысль, так как форма претендует  на полный контроль над содержанием, а этого не должно быть.  Форма  очень важна, но мы еще не изучили в полной мере ни ее истинного назначения, ни всех ее возможностей. Вы же сейчас стоите на консервативных позициях и поддерживаете  формализм, который и без вас является у нас ведущим принципом (вместо всех официально заявленных) и  поэтому в вашей поддержке не нуждается.

Comment: Ваш ответ ориентирован на формальные  правила, да только вряд ли по вашим рекомендациям можно сделать выбор. Это как раз тот случай, когда формальные правила не позволяют это сделать. Попробуйте решить хотя бы одну задачу с вариантами только  с  помощью правил, (например, выбор запятой, тире или двоеточия,  когда все они заявлены там как возможные),  и я посмотрю, что у вас получится. Или вот Розенталь говорит об «интонационном предупреждении», а пользователи попросту не понимают, что это значит.  Спасибо вам за внимание, отвечать не нужно.

Comment: Отказ приводить предложения с разными контекстами я расцениваю как ваше признание в поражении.
Вы не найдете ни одного примера во всей классической литературе, который бы подтверждал ответ того парня и опровергал бы мой ответ.

Comment: Розенталь — это очень плохая формализация. Максимум, на 2 из 10. Пункты плохо сформулированы, ничего не сгруппировано, не скомпанованно, пункты включают друг друга, пункты противоречат друг другу и тд. Темы в справочнике Розенталя — это большая дымящаяся куча хаотично сброшенных пунктов, просто нет ничего лучше.

Comment: Опять же, дабы выражать художественную мысль, вы должны использовать знаки, которые, что бы быть понятыми, должны быть формализованы и согласованны. Если этого нет, то вашу художественную мысль не поймет никто, кроме вас.