# Нужна ли запятая перед «как» в выделенном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, авторская-пунктуация, обороты-с-как

Напишу немного текста для понимания.

*Бытовало в народе и такое качество сердца, как буйность.* <...> *Их* [людей с буйным сердцем] *желание сохранять свою независимость иногда толкало на буйное поведение и непринятые в обществе поступки. **Человек с буйным сердцем был непредсказуем(,) как сама природа.** Он не боялся перемен и легко расставался с нажитым.*

Скажите, пожалуйста, здесь можно как ставить, так и не ставить запятую? Что здесь больше подходит, образ действия или сравнение?

Comment: Какое интересное предложение! Отвечать я скорее всего не буду, но скажу, почему оно кажется мне интересным. Оно почти на грани РАВНОВЕСИЯ. Кажется, если добавить еще одно маленькое по объему слово, то "весы" склонятся в сторону однозначности. (Как будто это настоящие весы!)  Такая ситуация не часто встречается...

Comment: Мне хотелось бы еще раз обратиться к нашей аудитории: пожалуйста, предлагайте ваши ответы. Сравнительный оборот – особая конструкция, а ваше мнение по этой теме – ну как ваша визитная карточка, что ли))  Хочется услышать самые простые суждения, без лишнего формализма,  даже без особых правил (всего этого уже и так хватает, не раз обсуждалось). Вот вы видите предложение, какое ваше первое впечатление? Стали бы вы обособлять оборот, если бы нужно было быстро сделать однозначный выбор  (на диктанте, например). Что бы потом подумали о своем решении?

Comment: P.S. 
Я, наверное, попыталась бы заглянуть в чью-нибудь тетрадь. На всякий случай…))

Comment: @Sharon Призыв принят, напишу, что думаю.

Comment: Класс! А за вами и другие подтянутся... Действительно, с теорией и лингвисты еще до конца не разобрались, а запятые всем приходится ставить.

Comment: @Sharon Назначение пунктуации – улучшить взаимопонимание в письменной речи через обозначения интонации и границ синтаксических сегментов. Взаимопонимание достигается через единые правила – следуя одинаковым правилам, мы понимаем назначения знаков, поставленных другими людьми. Размышления людей о многочисленных факторах постановки знаков, о каких-то эманациях, на основании которых они ставят те или иные знаки, их интуитивные рассуждения не относятся к правильной пунктуации, пока они не согласованны с другими людьми с помощью этих наших формализмов.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin
 Спасибо за ваше мнение, но я с вами не соглашусь. У нас принципиально разный подход к пониманию правил письма. Поэтому интуитивное восприятие правильности письменной речи для меня не менее ценно, чем знание правил. А в чем-то даже и более ценно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы был диктант (о чём пишет Sharon в комментарии), принять решение не составило бы труда. Наша учительница, читая текст, делала такие долгие, выразительные паузы, что почти ни у кого не возникало сомнения в запятой. Только вот, думаю, такое предложение не встретилось бы на диктанте... Из-за своей «нешкольности».
Не знаю, поможет ли мой ответ, потому что чем больше копаешься, тем больше колебаний – действительно, «Как будто это настоящие весы!» (Sharon).

**Примеры** мало что проясняют.

В Нацкорпусе русского языка из [18 случаев](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cq4CEooCCocCChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluEnwKJwoDbGV4EiAKHtCd0LXQv9GA0LXQtNGB0LrQsNC30YPQtdC80YvQuQoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAEnIKDwoDbGV4EggKBtCa0LDQugoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAQ==) с данным сочетанием (можно, конечно, много найти с другими словами) только несколько более или менее подходят по структуре к рассматриваемому предложению. Например:

*Река постоянно выходит из берегов, она **непредсказуема, как** женщина.*
*Погода у нас очень изменчива, но такая уж наша русская природа – **непредсказуемая, как** судьба…*

А вот с сайта «[Картаслов.ру](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)»:

*Меч ученика – **непредсказуемый как** убегающий заяц, меч мастера – **несокрушим как** водный поток.

Рассказы разные, непохожие друг на друга и **непредсказуемые как** наша жизнь.

Земляне не врали: он быстр как ветер, резок как надвигающийся шторм, и **непредсказуем как** песни луны.*

*Эти ансаларцы **непредсказуемы, как** сама погода.

А сюрпризы **непредсказуемы, как** сама жизнь.

Пески бесконечны, как время, и жестоки, как жизнь, и прекрасны, как вечные звёзды над ними, и **непредсказуемы, как** женский каприз, и незыблемы, как небесный свод.*

**Предложение из вопроса** делится на две фразы, и прочитать его можно с паузой в разных местах (если опять начнутся нескончаемые споры о паузах и ударениях – я в них участвовать не буду):

1. *Человек с буйным сердцем был непредсказ**У**ем, / как сама прир**О**да.*
2. *Человек с буйным с**Е**рдцем / был непредсказуем как сама прир**О**да.*

**Я выбираю второй вариант**, без запятой, и совсем не из-за отсутствия паузы.

Объяснить этот выбор по правилам ([Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147)) довольно сложно: действия как такового нет, «в качестве» не подходит, в состав сказуемого, скорее всего, оборот не входит, слово «непредсказуем» самодостаточно. Но мне видится следующее.
Здесь, кажется, можно применить «приравнивание или отождествление», а главное – тесную **смысловую** связь оборота с именной частью сказуемого, ведь в правилах мы снова видим пресловутое слово «обычно»: «**обычно** в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота». И ещё мне понравилось высказывание oleedd'a в комментариях о некоторой устойчивости фразы, что тоже склоняет «весы» в сторону отсутствия запятой.

«Буйный» человек независим от общества, живёт по сердцу, интуицией, **по-природному** (этакая замена оборота на наречие), он как бы и есть сама природа.

В таких, «на грани РАВНОВЕСИЯ» (Sharon), предложениях остаётся только ориентироваться на своё чувство языка и смысловые оттенки, вытекающие из общего характера текста.

**P. S.** Добавлю. Если это предложение, «голое», всё-таки встретилось бы в диктанте или тесте, я поставил бы запятую – чтоб никто не прикопался.

Comment: Спасибо за такой интересный ответ!

Comment: @Kirill  И вам за отличный вопрос!

Comment: Раньше вы не писали такие бредовые ответы. Кое-кто заразил вас болезнью сам не знаю что пишу.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin  Как же не писал?!  [Вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463975/Нужны-ли-запятые-где-два-обстоятельства-подряд/463980#463980), например. И ваш комментарий: "Как такой высокий рейтинг сочетается с этим безумным бредом, что вы написали?"

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Александр, мы с вами выбрали одинаковое решение, что и радует. Но, признаться, пришли к нему 
  разными путями. Должно ли это меня огорчать? Почему-то не огорчает...  Может быть, я надеюсь на то, что интуиция и чувство языка подсказывали нам верный путь и мало внимания обращали на наши мысли. Поэтому я голосую за ваш ответ:)

Comment: @Sharon Очень приятно, спасибо! Ваш путь тоже очень интересен.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец   А какой у меня путь, вы разве знаете :))

Comment: @Sharon Я к тому, что хотелось бы лицезреть его!

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Он так прост, что боюсь вас и всех остальных разочаровать. Может быть, чуть позже...

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Просто в предложении я бы тоже поставила запятую, причем почти не сомневаясь. Но в контексте уверенно выбираю второй вариант без обособления, что и интересно. Если не будет других ответов, то отвечу завтра. Кое-что новое хотелось бы сказать.

Answer (score 3):

**Обособление сравнительного оборота** ***NEW*!**

**ИНТОНАЦИОННО-СТРУКТУРНЫЙ АНАЛИЗ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ** (как основной вариант при решении сложных задач)

**1. ТЕОРИЯ**

При ответе использованы материалы по теме [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473791/Приложение-это-сравнительный-оборот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473791/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82)

**В трехчастных конструкциях с двойными связями** (два предмета/признака сравниваются через действие/состояние) могут проявляться в большей мере:

— обстоятельственные отношения (предмет действует как?);

— признаковые/определительные отношения (предмет/признак какой?).

При обособлении мы подчеркиваем ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение, а при отсутствии обособления — ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВЕННОЕ, причем в какой-то мере это зависит от ПОЗИЦИИ оборота в предложении.

Итак, мы не можем найти **однозначное соответствие** между значением оборота и его обособлением, поэтому такой анализ (это определение или обстоятельство?) **неэффективен**. Лучше уделить основное внимание **структурному анализу.**

**2. СТРУКТУРА**

Из теории для сравнительного оборота (СО) можно сделать следующие **выводы** о его структуре.

(1) Обособление – это **основной вариант** для СО, а отсутствие обособления – вариант возможный.

(2) Чем ближе оборот **к подлежащему**, тем вероятнее его обособление (замечание из учебника Прияткиной).

(3) Нераспространенный оборот в конце предложения **чаще не обособляется**, так как он попадает в ударную позицию (так проявляется обстоятельственное значение оборота).

**3. РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

(1) Рассмотрим предложение: ***Человек с буйным сердцем был непредсказуем(,) как сама природа**.*

Это классический (**трехчастный**) оборот: сравниваются человек и природа через отношение к предикативному признаку «непредсказуем».

(2) Структура близка  **к равновесной**: оборот  распространён и при этом не смещен к подлежащему, хотя полного равновесия все-таки нет. Поэтому появляются сомнения.

(3) Если мы анализируем отдельное предложение, то выбираем **основной (частотный)** вариант с обособлением оборота: ***Человек с буйным сердцем / был непредсказУем, как сама прирОда.*** При обособлении оборота сообщение выглядит законченным,  что видно по расстановке ударений.

(4) Но **в контексте** ситуация будет другой: ведь начатая тема будет в дальнейшем продолжена.

При отсутствии обособления оборот в конце предложения **логически подчеркивается**, а далее будет следовать **раскрытие темы** (законченность здесь уже не нужна).  Поэтому оборот не обособляется:

***Человек с буйным сердцем / был непредсказуем как сама прирОда***.  (По основному ударению **в конце** предложения чувствуется, что мысль будет продолжена дальше.)

**Вывод**. Пояснительный текст не получился коротким, но само решение находится быстро. Вы **СМОТРИТЕ** на предложение – и вы **ЗНАЕТЕ** это решение.  Или чувствуете, это уж кто как)))

Comment: Я знаю откуда термин ‟логически подчёркнут”. Он из справочника Розенталя, из главы про тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Он использовал этот термин подразумевая то же, что и логическое ударение (ударение Святого Иосифа). Вот пример оттуда: ‟Я — страница твоему перу”. Вы говорите, что если не поставить запятую, то оборот будет логически подчёркнут.  Нет, не будет он под логическим ударением. Я отчётливо объяснил, что такое логическое ударение в своём вопросе.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не размещайте здесь комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения моего ответа. Для критики  вы можете использовать поле ответа. Пожалуйста, не нарушайте правила сайта.

Comment: Это предложение улучшение, то есть удалить эту часть ответа, а лучше вообще весь ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно!

Comment: @Kirill
 Пожалуйста, если интересно. Но я вам не верю...))

Comment: Странно, почему? Я впервые стакливаюсь с такими теоретическими выкладками, и это интересно. А Ваш ответ понятен.

Comment: @Kirill  Я чувствую, интуиция))  А теоретические выкладки  эти все уже читали, но сейчас вот молчат. Не понравилось им интуитивное решение. А я вот о чем задумалась. Я действительно задачи решаю интуитивно, но потом оформляю ответ, чтобы "не прикопались". Рассуждения, рассуждения... А так ли они хороши, к примеру, в этой теме. Приводят ли они к однозначному выбору, хотя и делается вид, что это так.  И наши участники (в большинстве своем) недовольны, что какое-то интуитивное "чувство" конкурирует с логикой мышления. Вот и молчат...

Comment: @Kirill Наверное, чем бредовей ответ, тем более вероятность, что вы его выберете. А почему тогда мой ответ про яйца вам не понравился?

Comment: @Kirill Пожалуйста, верните приемку ответа, как было. Мой ответ внеконкурсный, я даже специально подождала, пока вы сделаете выбор, а потом ответила. Их нельзя сравнивать, у меня просто эксперимент.

Comment: Я не заметил, что зеленая галка исчезла на ответе Александра, не знал, что нельзя нажимать на разные ответы. Кажется не справедливым, если 2 или несколько ответов (вообще) являются одинаково полезными, грамотными и помогающими решить вопрос.  А со своими яйцами, Румпельстилцкин, разбирайтесь сами.

Comment: @Sharon Если это интонационная запятая, то почему в таком предложении ставится запятая: ‟Камни дробились, как стекло” (он из какого-то учебник, и я не помню из какого)? Или в таком: ‟Иной раз подстрелишь зайца, ранишь его в ногу, а он кричит, словно ребёнок (Ч.)”; или в таком: ‟И грусть на дне старинной раны зашевелилася, как змей (Л.)”; или в таком: ‟Низко подвешенные лампочки светились, как в тумане”; или в таком: ‟Гляжу, как безумный, на чёрную шаль (П.).” Не существует вообще предложений с более короткими паузами перед сравнительными оборотами, но при этом здесь запятые стоят.

Comment: После таких предложений везде нужно ставить запятую по интуиции. Вы справочник Розенталя не читали, вы не видели множество подобных предложений в другим местах, прежде чем нести эту чушь про ударения, про равновесие? И либо отвечайте на мой вопрос про ударение, либо удаляйте свои ответы с этим термином.

Comment: Я лучше отвечу, а то удалять ответы придется...  В ваших примерах запятая обязательно нужна, какие могут быть сомнения. Это мне интуиция подсказывает))

Answer (score 1):

Если сравнительный оборот относится не к глаголу (а в данном случае он относится к прилагательному), то он не обособляется, только если является сказуемым или фразеологизмом, а здесь это не так. Споры о сравнительных оборотах касаются ситуаций, когда характеристика действия или не характеристика действия, а если сравнительный оборот относится к прилагательному, то он не может означать характеристику действия.

В итоге: Человек с буйным сердцем был непредсказуем, как сама природа.

Стоит добавить, что [все примеры из Нац. корпуса](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cq4CEooCCocCChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluEnwKJwoDbGV4EiAKHtCd0LXQv9GA0LXQtNGB0LrQsNC30YPQtdC80YvQuQoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAEnIKDwoDbGV4EggKBtCa0LDQugoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAQ==) с запятой. Очевидно, что если где-то и есть пример без запятой, то там нет запятой по причинам хаотичной пунктуации, а не по причинам какого-то замысла.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146695/discussion-on-answer-by-rumpelstiltskin-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

**Еще один ответ от 26.12.2023г.**

Неужели этот вопрос обсуждался всего лишь полгода назад! А мне казалось, что года два прошло, так много изменилось. Я сама как будто другая, и **интонационное** решение тоже видится иначе. Оно имеет более **простую** формулировку: **два ударения или одно ударение** (только на обороте). И мне захотелось непредвзято взглянуть на тему, как бы увидеть вопрос снова.

1. Я по-прежнему уверена в том, что решение об обособлении оборота в трехчастной конструкции (два предмета, человек и природа, сравниваются через состояние (непредсказуем) —**неоднозначно.**  И просто хочу **прочитать текст** или с двумя ударениями (обособление), или с одним ударением, когда оно переходит с предмета на оборот.
2. Обособление в таких предложениях — это **основное** решение, для перехода ударения на оборот нужна **причина**. И вот **сейчас** я понимаю, как много зависит **от контекста**. Того, что приведено,  мне **недостаточно**. Надо понять, что здесь **важнее**: обозначить **непредсказуемость** в основном сообщении (оборот будет обособленным сравнением) или подчеркнуть связь с природой (непредсказуем **как природа**).
3. Но нет **четкой подсказки про природу**, и тогда я читаю с обособлением и двумя ударениями (выбираю **основной** вариант):

(1) *Человек с буйным сердцем был непредсказУем, **как сама прирОда**.* Он не боялся перемен и легко расставался с нажитым.

4. А что я там говорила про **одно слово,** которое может изменить ситуацию? Оборот здесь **распространенный,** вот что! Надо **слово "сама"** убрать:

(2) *Человек с буйным сердцем был **непредсказуем как прирОда**.* Он не боялся перемен и легко расставался с нажитым.

Answer (score 0):

Буйность - это качество, как определено в предложении до. Получается что: человек - подлежащее, с буйным сердцем - сказуемое, - то есть "человек обладающий независимым поведением". Получается, что уже предложение сложное:

*Человек с буйным сердцем - был непредсказуем, как сама природа.*

Либо так:

*Человек с буйным сердцем - был непредсказуем как сама природа.*

Смотря к какому слову относится как сама природа: к слову был - "был как природа" был природным или непредсказуемо-природным, диким по природе то есть; или к слову непредсказуем - "непредсказуем, как сама природа", - то есть дикий, словно нерукотворная природа.

В ином случае можно было бы и запятой обойтись вместо тире:

*Человек с буйным сердцем, был непредсказуем, как сама природа.*

Но выбор тире и постановка запятой перед *как* зависит от того, шла ли речь дальше про природу, или в каком ключе упоминалась природа, для условности и красного словца или для уравнивания "человек *с буйным сердцем* = естественный, природный человек".
Так что однозначно определить можно только имея весь текст перед глазами, ну или хотя бы продолжение.

А вот такие варианты мне кажутся наименее оправданными:

*Человек с буйным сердцем был непредсказуем, как сама природа.*

*Человек с буйным сердцем, был непредсказуем как сама природа.*

Фраза же совсем без знаков препинания читается тяжеловесно, и упускается момент условности, что буйность - это качество...

*Человек с буйным сердцем был непредсказуем как сама природа.*

Так что тоже вряд ли.